# Data Wrangling for Analysis Services Cube

Tags: r, sql-server, database, ssis, ssas

I have a data set that is as follows (simplified):

```
Fund    Field1-2012    Field1-2013    Field2-2012   Field2-2013
 FD1       x               x               x            x
 FD2       x               x               x            x
```

As you can see, dates exist with the fields making this very unfriendly for most analysis. What  want is the following

```
Fund   Year   Field1   Field2
 FD1    2012   x          x
 FD1    2013   x          x
 FD2    2012   x          x
 FD2    2013   x          x
```

I have been using SQL server integration tools to accomplish this but to no avail. Is there a tool I should be using or is there something in excel that can help me out? Not possible to brute force as the dataset is quite large

Best

Comment: You should be able to reshape your data, extract the year (numeric part) from each value and then reshape again.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by this?   "I have been using SQL server integration tools to accomplish this but to no avail."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have an R tag, so here's an R solution:

```
df = read.table(text = "
Fund    Field1-2012    Field1-2013    Field2-2012   Field2-2013
FD1       5               7               9            10
FD2       6               8               9            10
", header=T)

library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  gather(key, value, -Fund) %>%
  separate(key, c("type","year"), convert = T) %>%
  spread(type, value)

#   Fund year Field1 Field2
# 1  FD1 2012      5      9
# 2  FD1 2013      7     10
# 3  FD2 2012      6      9
# 4  FD2 2013      8     10
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `apply` to unpivot the data :

```
select t.Fund, tt.year, tt.Field1, tt.Field2
from table t cross apply
     ( values (2012, [Field1-2012], [Field2-2012]), 
              (2013, [Field1-2013], [Field2-2013]) 
     ) tt (year, Field1, Field2);
```

Answer (score 1):

One option would be to use `union all`:

```
select fund, 2012 as year, Field1-2012 as field1, Field2-2012 as field2
from yourtable
union all
select fund, 2013 as year, Field1-2013 as field1, Field2-2013 as field2
from yourtable
```